# Query table and Select latest 2 rows (in SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that logs all updates made to an application. I want to query the table and return the last update by [Timestamp] and the update before that for a different value [ITEM]. I'm struggling to figure out how to get what i need. I'm returning more than one record for each ID and don't want that.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        LAG(ITEM) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS ITEM, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) RN 
    FROM   
        MyLoggingTable
    WHERE  
        accountid = 1234
) 
SELECT 
    cte.ID, 
    dl.ITEM, 
    DL.timestamp 
FROM
    cte 
JOIN 
    MyLoggingTable DL ON cte.ID = DL.ID 
WHERE  
    rn = 1 
    AND cte.ID IN ('id here | Sub select :( ..')
```

Comment: You are joining back to the MyLoggingTable again after the cte so you are going to get all the rows that you went to the trouble of eliminating. Return Item and timestamp in your cte then you will be fine. FWIW, you should avoid reserved words like timestamp for object and column names as it makes things more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Hmm, i have that join there because without it i can't get to the second to last ITEM. When i remove it ITEM is all blank for all rows returned which it shouldn't be. Perhaps, i'm not explaining it properly. On the timestamp thing i know.. it bothers me too but i didn't create this, just need to work with it.

Comment: Maybe you change the where clause to be "rn <= 2"? Perhaps you need to share some details so we all know what the issue really is. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great example.

Comment: Understood, the rn <=2 also returned more. I'll change it up tonight/tomorrow, appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ID unique? Because if it is, your code shouldn't return duplicates. If it isn't, you will get duplicates because you are joining back to the `MyLoggingTable` which isn't needed. You should just move those columns (`dl.Item` & `dl.timestamp`) into the `cte` and return them from the `cte` like you did `cte.ID`.

I removed the `LAG` since you didn't return that column in your final query.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        ITEM, 
        [timestamp], 
        --LAG(ITEM) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS ITEM, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) RN 
    FROM   
        MyLoggingTable
    WHERE  
        accountid = 1234
) 
SELECT 
    cte.ID, 
    cte.ITEM, 
    cte.timestamp 
FROM
    cte 
WHERE  
    rn = 1 
    AND cte.ID IN ('id here | Sub select :( ..')
```

Note, if you wanted the second to the last item, as you stated in your comments, make `rn=2`

Comment: That did it! with rn=2 i got the second to last row. I really appreciate that!

Comment: No sweat at all